# Making a hole in a mesh while keeping the integrity of texture

Tags: animation

So I'm attempting to create an animation where an image has a hole appear in it, and then the camera zooms through the hole. I tried using shape keys, but since the uv unwrap is mapped for one shape key, it gets messed up when transferred to the other shape key. Is there a way to make this possible?

Comment: Could you please edit your question and provide more info about what you are trying to achieve, maybe some reference pictures and screenshots of what you currently got? It's not very clear what you are trying to do

Comment: No time for an answer, but here is an example using an alpha map. http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2378/

Answer (score 2):

Well I figured it out. The best way for me to keep the integrity of my texture was to go into the node editor and change the "texture coordinates" to "Object" instead of "uv coordinates"
Thanks a bunch you guys! :)